SpherePoints problem
Cited from https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/SpherePoints.html?q=SpherePoints

SpherePoints[n] gives the positions of n uniformly distributed
points on the surface of a unit sphere.
SpherePoints[n] gives exactly equally spaced points in certain cases
for small n. In other cases, it places points so they are
approximately equally spaced.

But for n=8 where we have a cube (platonic solid) the output neither seems to be exactly equally spaced nor approximately equally spaced.
Is it a bug or I am missing something? I have not tested for other values of n.
pts = SpherePoints[8];

pts2 = Flatten[{#, -#} & /@ SpherePoints[4], 1];

Graphics3D[{DelaunayMesh[pts], Opacity[0.5], Sphere[], Red, 
  PointSize[Large], Point[pts]}, ImageSize -> Small]

Graphics3D[{DelaunayMesh[pts2], Opacity[0.5], Sphere[], Red, 
  PointSize[Large], Point[pts2]}, ImageSize -> Small]



Solved with @Domen's comment that the exact definition of SpherePoints can be found in Spherical Code and is as follows (not same as in documentation):

How can n points be distributed on a unit sphere such that they
maximize the minimum distance between any pair of points?


Looking at DistanceMatrix[pts] // MatrixForm shows that each point is equidistant from 4 other points.

They may be, but they are not equally spaced on the surface of the sphere. There is a better distribution - a cube.

From perspective of projection of centers of the triangles the density of points around them is larger than from perspective of centers of squares.

You can certainly have all of the distances being equal for 2, 3, and 4 points.  But is that even possible for all points being the same distance away from each other with 5 or more points?  (Or is that not the issue?)

Do you think that pts2 is more equally spaced than pts?  What test would you use to show this?

@JasonB Isn't it straightforward? I have already wrote in previous comment. Density of points in the region above square in the first figure is lower than density of points in the region above triangles. You do even have to compute it is evident just by sight, but certainly you can compute if you wish. The cube being a platonic solid does not have this issue.

So you don't know what is meant by 'equally spaced' any more than I do?  I don't know how straightforward it is - I assume there is some quality of the distance matrix that can help answer it.  Maybe relevant

@JasonB Do you realize that the squares in the first figure are the same squares as in the second figure but twisted 45 degrees? But since they are twisted the opposite squares get closer to each other thus making the distribution more uneven compared to cube.

Instead of assuming there is a bug, just invest more time in googling: Spherical Code. Min@DeleteCases[DistanceMatrix[pts], 0., All] is 1.22, while Min@DeleteCases[DistanceMatrix[pts2], 0., All] is 1.15.

@Domen Have you read? Because the definition on that page "How can n points be distributed on a unit sphere such that they maximize the minimum distance between any pair of points?" is not the same as stated in the documentation of SpherePoints. There is no reference to any distance between points but "uniformly distributed points on the surface". And this is a big difference. If that was written in the documentation I would have no problem with it. But if we talk about even distribution on the surface (area) then the cube is the solution not the other figure.

I've given you the answer about what SpherePoints does. If you believe the documentation is unclear, there is nothing we can do about it here. Send your complaints and rants to the Wolfram Support.

If you image the points to be electrical charged and considers the energy, then the configuration with 45 degree rotated faces has lower energy. Therefore, I would vote for this configuration to be more evenly distributed..

By the way, spherical code, which deals with distances,  has nothing to do with uniformity.

@yarchik - the 'spherical code' linked above is implemented in Mathematica as SpherePoints

@Daniel Huber GraphLayout -> "SpringEmbedding" gives cube. There is no "only electrical" embedding though. But I am inclined to think it would give also cube. But again it is another definition of "evenness" and they do not have to coincide with each other. The points is to express the definition of someone's "evenness" precisely, which I think was not the case in the documentation.

What was wrong with the question for (-1)? Was it unevenly distributed? :-D

Some links associated with the author of SpherePoints:  https://scholar.rose-hulman.edu/cgi/viewcontent.cgi?article=1387&context=rhumj and https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rwV_dAlWWnw.

@azerbajdzan If you calculate the energy of both cases, you will see that the rotated configuration has slightly lower energy. The pairwise energy goes like 1/ distance.

The downvote is from me. Your question fails in multiple ways, and I wish I could downvote more. Here's why:

You answer your own question in your own post. Instead of posting your answer and seeing which one wins votes, you're essentially preaching. This approach leaves no room for feedback, which goes against the collaborative nature of Stack Exchange.
I disagree with your proposed solution.
3)Your post is formulated in a way that prevents any meaningful answers. In its current form, I don't see how any answer could ever be accepted, which means the post will keep resurfacing.


I hope this picture is self-explanatory. I use the so-called Lambert cylindrical equal area projection which maps the sphere to a cylinder, area to equal area. Please, notice periodicity along each direction. Equivalent sides are of the same colour.
SphPts = SpherePoints[8];
CbcPts = Flatten[{#, -#} & /@ SpherePoints[4], 1];
Graphics[{PointSize[Large], Black, 
     Point[Table[{(Sin[u[[2]] - Pi/2] + 1)/2, 
                  (u[[3]] + Pi)/(2 Pi)},
           {u, ToSphericalCoordinates@#[[1]]}]], 
     Thick, Purple, 
     Line[{{0, 0}, {0, 1}}], Line[{{1, 0}, {1, 1}}], 
     Orange, 
     Line[{{0, 0}, {1, 0}}], Line[{{0, 1}, {1, 1}}]}, 
    PlotLabel -> #[[2]]] & /@ 
 {{SphPts, "SpherePoints[8]"}, {CbcPts, "CubePoints"}} // GraphicsRow



I guess the projection depends on the position of the figures to the cylinder. Are the squares of the figures parallel to top and bottom of the cylinder in both cases? If I am not mistaken they are not.

@azerbajdzan Yes. It is indeed interesting if there is a rotation of the sphere that makes cubic point look uniform under the Lambert project. I do not know.

I am not sure you know what I mean . Use these vertices SphPts = PolyhedronData["SquareAntiprism", "VertexCoordinates"]; CbcPts = PolyhedronData["Cube", "VertexCoordinates"]; You will see that cube vertices are better distributed.

And a second point, even if you projected sphere to a cylinder of the same area that does not mean that even distribution of points on sphere would be preserved on a projection to a cylinder.

Image with vertices from previous comment https://i.sstatic.net/TMj5vBfJ.png.

@azerbajdzan Thanks for the plot. I argue that they are not better distributed. Rather, both distributions are of the same quality from the point of view of the Lambert projection. Concerning your next comment. One way to define uniform distribution is via area. But if you have a different rigorous mathematical definition of "uniform", please, present it. There could be many definitions, my point of view is that both, MA documentation and your OP does not define the meaning of  "uniform".

If somebody talk about distribution of points on surface (surface=area) like in the documentation without any further explanations what else should I speculate about than that it is meant as distribution over area. If I told you give me random points evenly distributed on a surface of a square wouldn't you assume that it is meant over area?

This is just out of curiosity regarding @DanielHuber comment.

If you image the points to be electrical charged and considers the
energy, then the configuration with 45 degree rotated faces has lower
energy. Therefore, I would vote for this configuration to be more
evenly distributed.

Graph3D with GraphLayout -> "SpringElectricalEmbedding" outputs cube which can be verified by DistanceMatrix that is same as for cube.
Graph3D[{{1, 2}, {2, 4}, {4, 3}, {3, 1}, {5, 6}, {6, 8}, {8, 7}, {7, 
   5}, {2, 6}, {4, 8}, {3, 7}, {1, 5}}, VertexLabels -> Automatic, 
 GraphLayout -> "SpringElectricalEmbedding"]

DeleteDuplicates[GraphEmbedding[%] // DistanceMatrix // Flatten, 
 Abs[#1 - #2] < 0.01 &]

{0, 1, Sqrt[2], Sqrt[3]} // N



{0., 0.999451, 1.41355, 1.73142}

{0., 1., 1.41421, 1.73205}

